# How can I condense information coming in from Google Forms into something that is uniform and easy follow?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-forms

I am currently working on setting up a sign up where people can select the number of kids/people they are signing up for in Google Forms, and then the form takes them to a section where they can sign up the exact number they put. The issue is, because of the way Google Forms is set up, the information being placed into Google Sheets goes all over the place.

To remedy this, I created a formula that runs on a separate sheet that takes this spread out information and condenses it so all the information lines up correctly. Here is the formula:

```
=if('RS1'!G3<>"",ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(D3,'RS1'!$D$3:$CL,{4,5,6,7},false)),
if('RS1'!K3<>"",ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(D3,'RS1'!$D$3:$CL,{8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15},false)),
if('RS1'!S3<>"",ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(D3,'RS1'!$D$3:$CL,{16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27},false)),
if('RS1'!AE3<>"",ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(D3,'RS1'!$D$3:$CL,{28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43},false)),
if('RS1'!AU3<>"",ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(D3,'RS1'!$D$3:$CL,{44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63},false)),
if('RS1'!BO3<>"",ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(D3,'RS1'!$D$3:$CL,{64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87},false)),""))))))
```

Although this formula I came up with works alright, I was wondering: Is there was another, more simplified way to achieve the same results? If so, how would I go about setting this up?

Here is the link to the spreadsheet if any of you would like to take a look:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GdzigMHAxPqcr589H5178brsBIuYgU4NVk8OBOr5pSU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Jacob, your sheet is locked ("Access Denied"). Please set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: I just barely updated the permissions. Let me know if you have trouble accessing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Particularly considering that you have that huge formula dragged down and active in nearly 1000 rows, I can absolutely condense things for you.

This one formula in G3 produces all results for all  rows in G:AD ...

`=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(INDIRECT("RS1!G3:CL")="","~",INDIRECT("RS1!G3:CL")&"|"))," ",COLUMNS(INDIRECT("RS1!G3:CL")))),INDIRECT("RS1!A3:A")<>""),"~",""),"|",0,1))`

As for *how* it works, that is tricky to explain, but I'll give the "condensed" version.

In short, I replaced any blank with a character I know you'll never use ("~"), appended a second character you'll never use ("|") to anything that *wasn't* blank, and then used a quirk of the QUERY function to condense all of that into as many "header rows" for that QUERY as there are actual rows. Then I used SUBSTITUTE to weed out the tildes ("~") and SPLIT what was left at the pipes ("|"), choosing parameters to "split at any group of pipes as a whole" (0) and "remove blanks created by this splitting process" (1).

Answer (score 0):

A way of making the formula smaller is to use `OFFSET`. Note though that it's not possible to use `ARRAYFORMULA` with it. To make all the results with a single formula, you need to parse it to string and work with it (see Erik's answer).

If you only want it row by row I think this is simpler and easier to understand:

```
=IF('RS1'!$A3<>"",
  {
    'RS1'!$A3:$F3,
    OFFSET('RS1'!$G3, 0, 2*'RS1'!$F3*('RS1'!$F3-1), 1, 4*'RS1'!$F3)
  },
  ""
)
```

The most important part is the `OFFSET`. Here is all the used arguments:

1. The starting cell is `G3` (first column of the first child).
2. It doesn't have any vertical offset (so 0).
3. For the horizontal offset it uses `2*n*(n-1)` where `n` is the number of children (see below).
4. Numbers of rows. Only one.
5. Number of columns. Each kid has 4 columns, thus `4*n` where `n` is the number of children.

So from the cell `G3` prespective, the first 4 columns are the first child. Then the next 8 if they have 2 childs. This goins up to `n-1` (since we start at 0):

[image: 1\times4+2\times4+3\times4+...+(n-1)\times4]

If we group the times 4 and apply the formula for [the sum of naturals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) from `1` to `n-1`:

[image: 4[1+2+3+...+(n-1)]=4\frac{(n-1)(n-1+1)}{2}=2n(n-1)]

Change `n` for `'RS1'!$F3` and you get what to use as offset.

Now we only need to add the initial columns (`A3:F3`) with the result of `OFFSET` and add a conditional to prevent errors for trying to use `Fn` as a number.

### References

- [OFFSET function (Google Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en)
- [Using arrays in Google Sheets (Google Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)
- [1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ⋯ (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the problem, but this formula in cell A3 on the tab called MK.Help might be all you need.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('RS1'!A3:CL&CHAR(10)),,9^99))),CHAR(10)&" ",0,1)))
```